# User has many images and user.article has many images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to give User the ability to add an Image, but would like to allow then to add one of those images to an Article. I'm curious if I would have to create two separate models for Image and ArticleImage? It would be great if I could use the same Image model to do both jobs, but as of now the only way I could think to do it is two separate models, like this.

routes.rb

```
resources :users do 
  resources :images
  resources :articles do
    resources :articles_images
  end
end
```

I feel pretty sure it would be advised against to do something like this, although it's tempting:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :images
  resources :articles do
    resources :images
  end
end
```

My assumption is that if I take the first approach, articles_images would just be a join table to store an image_id and article_id, is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with just one Image model.

Users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
end
```

Article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :images
end
```

Image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users
resources :images
resources :articles
```

In your images controller, add your images through your current user -

```
def create
    @image = current_user.images.build(params[:image])
```

For the final step, there are multiple ways to assign the already created images to a specific article. You would create a custom route and custom method in your images controller to handle this.

Comment: i see where you are going with that, but it seems like i lose the /users/1/images routes with this method? also lose /users/1/articles routes?

Comment: You could still make those routes that way without affecting the models at all.